# Android save TextView background color on screen rotation

Tags: android, textview

Problem is that, when screen changes orientation, textview background color is gone.
here is TextView definition:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nomResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:text="Nom result"
    android:layout_below="@id/svitrkods"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/svitrkods" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/exit_button"
    android:freezesText="true"
    />
```

App is inventory app. When product is already in inventory, then i am displaying text in textview with red background. `vaiIrInvent.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);` that works. but when screen rotates, background color is gone...
When application stars, i save original background color of textview `defBackColor = vaiIrInvent.getBackground();`
then in app i am switching to red or default.

```
if (isInInventory)
{
    vaiIrInvent.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
}
else
{
    vaiIrInvent.setBackgroundDrawable(defBackColor);
}
```

Maybe there is some option like android:freezesText ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my situation is:
save scanned barcode when screen orientation changes

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Save entered code 
  savedInstanceState.putString("svkKods", svkKods.getText().toString());
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and restore code and query db.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  String mystr = savedInstanceState.getString("svkKods");
  svkKods.setText(mystr);
  //if code presents 
  if (mystr.length() > 3) FindKods(mystr); //query database and fill all texts and variables
}
```

i am doing this way because in a variable is stored state, when barcode is found in database and then user can submit changes. otherwise is displayed message to must find barcode ...

Answer (score 1):

yup rotion calls onCreate()  you need to save information to restore preferences

this link should explain it a little better

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

Comment: I this already found, now i am looking how to save Drawable object
I am thinking that my problem is little bit bigger. because i have 2 views. one in layout folder and one in layout-land. when screen rotates i need figure out if background is set and then pass background to landscape layout. Or its not good idea?

Comment: problem is much bigger than i think. when screen rotates, all variables are gone. I need trigger action to edittext to re-query database. tomorrow i will continue to search some solutions. variables data i can save in `onSaveInstanceState` . Of course i can lock app in horizontal or in vertical, but i don't like that solution..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you lose `isInInventory` state on rotation because by default OS creates a new `Activity` instance in this case. If this is the case, then the best way is to use save/restore state callbacks the `Activity` class exposes. Check this for details: [Saving activity state](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState).